# Com Bootstrap, como posicionar o botão ao fim do card?

Tags: html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

gostaria de uma solução para posicionar um botão sempre ao fim do card, para que ele não dependa do tamanho do texto acima, ou tamanho pre-definido do objeto anterior.

Para exemplificar aqui está o link do jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/whositalo/qg5k4p1r/6/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="container">
 <div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card text-center mb-4">
     <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="https://s.dicio.com.br/exemplo.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card"></a>
                        <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Exemplo</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Este é um texto de exemplo pequeno.</p>
    <a  href="#" class="btn btn-info">Ver mais</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card text-center mb-4">
   <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="https://s.dicio.com.br/exemplo.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card"></a>
   <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Outro Exemplo</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Este é um texto de exemplo maior, para exemplificar o ploblema. Gostaria que os botões ficassem posicionados sempre no fim do card, mas no card ao lado, ele fica acima. Como poderia resolver isso?</p>
    <a href="/crack.html" class="btn btn-info">Ver mais</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na div com classe `Card-body` vc vai usar as seguintes classes de Flex do proprio bootstrap `d-flex flex-column align-items-center` para consultar mais veja o link oficial https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Depois disso no link vc coloca `mt-auto`, que seria o mesmo que `margin-top: auto`, isso vai "empurrar" o botão para o  final do `card`

Veja o código abaixo repare que não tem CSS extra, tudo foi feito com as classes do próprio Bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card text-center mb-4">
          <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="https://s.dicio.com.br/exemplo.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card"></a>
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">Exemplo</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Este é um texto de exemplo pequeno.</p>
          <a  href="#" class="btn btn-info mt-auto">Ver mais</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card text-center mb-4">
        <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="https://s.dicio.com.br/exemplo.jpg" alt="Imagem de capa do card"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Outro Exemplo</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Este é um texto de exemplo maior, para exemplificar o ploblema. Gostaria que os botões ficassem posicionados sempre no fim do card, mas no card ao lado, ele fica acima. Como poderia resolver isso?</p>
          <a href="/crack.html" class="btn btn-info">Ver mais</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Resolvido! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @ItaloAraujo de nada meu caro! Abs